# js map function index does not increment

Tags: reactjs, mapping, javascript-objects

probably missing something obvious but my map function's index param will not increment up its just stuck as 0 or whatever static index I set it to, maybe I'm missing something because my data structure im passing in is an array of objects like:

(20) -> [{},{},{}]

and each object has quite a few properties
I'll provide my map function below for greater context

also I can manually change my index and my code works fine grabbing an object at whatever index I specify i.e '5' or '13' and my depth is correct because its displaying the property values as it should, wondering if I need to nest something to make this work?

if I console log my state I have this structure here just an array of objects
[image]

```
//storing to state

componentDidMount(){
        
        fetch(`https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/feed?start_date=${this.state.time[0]}&end_date=${this.state.time[1]}&api_key=ipAxYzaENbqRKb7GgzFPcH6QUBsHXY3QKB7uXOf5`
        )
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        let ast = []
        Object.values(data.near_earth_objects).forEach((arr)=>{
            //push the two arrays together
            ast.push(...arr)
        })
        this.setState({asteroids:[ast]})
       
      });
    }





render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h4>Near earth objects</h4>

                <table>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Magnitude</th>
                        <th>Hazardous</th>
                        <th>Sentry Object</th>
                    </tr>
                  
                { 
                
                this.state.asteroids.map((arr,index)=>(
                    //for each item (arr) there will be properties
                    
                <tr key={arr.toString()}>
                    <td >{arr[index].name}</td>
                    <td >{arr[index].id}</td>
                    <td >{arr[index].absolute_magnitude_h}</td>
                    <td >{arr[index].is_potentially_hazardous_asteroid==true? "true": "false"}</td>
                    <td >{arr[index].is_sentry_object==true? "true": "false"}</td>
                    <td > index {index}</td>
                </tr> 
                
                ))  
                 
            }
            </tbody>
            </table>
                
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Comment: If I am not wrong your `this.state.asteroids` is an array of object . If that is the case you can just do `arr.name` and `arr.id` .

Comment: I tried that a bit ago but it seems to just ignore the object altogether and renders nothing for the properties within map() I have updated the code with a clearer understanding of my object structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in componentDidMount when you setState of asteroids your taking the array and putting it inside another array

```
  this.setState({asteroids:[ast]})
  // instead it should be 
  this.setState({asteroids: ast })
```

Checkout this codesandbox with a working example of your code https://codesandbox.io/s/empty-forest-jvwin?file=/src/App.tsx

As for why the index is stuck, it's because the asteroids array in your example has only 1 element (the array that is holding all the asteroids data).

Comment: ah thanks that did the trick I completely missed that thank you for the example :)